# How to sort Array of string in specific string index

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

So.. Actually, I have a list that has multiple strings on it. And here I want to sort it  in specific strings index :

```
lists = ['AELIA4560005253120', 'KIFLA5000005760000']
```

Soo.. inside of the lists, there are names (which has caps word in it), code (3 number digits after the name), and secret number (10 digits of code after the previous code).. my question is, can I sort this list by specific strings index which I want to **sort it by code** (3 number digits after the name)??

```
# expecting lists after sort
lists_sort = ['KIFLA5000005760000','AELIA4560005253120']
```

So my expected result is, KIFLA came first and AELIA is second is because KIFLA's codes are 500 and AELIA's codes are 456

Can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: Are the names always the same length?

Comment: Nope.. only the secret codes have the same length which is 10 digit of last codes.

Comment: So then the answer you accepted will break if the names are not exactly five letters long.

Comment: Yea, But thanks to the answer, I can improvise the code by changing the index by reverse the index itself which the codes become like this..                                           res = sorted(lists, key=lambda x: int(x[-13:-10]), reverse = True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lists = ['AELIA4560005253120', 'KIFLA5000005760000']

res = sorted(lists, key=lambda x: int(x[5:8]) , reverse = True)
#['KIFLA5000005760000', 'AELIA4560005253120']
```

Comment: You probably want int(x[5:8]) in the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name is of a variable length, you can use this:

```
import re

lists = ['AELIA4560005253120', 'KIFLA5000005760000']

lists_sort = sorted(lists, key = lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d{3}', x).group(0)), reverse = True)
print(lists_sort)
```

Comment: I wonder if `int(re.search(r'\d{3}', s).group(0))` would be easier?

Comment: yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the answer